# Criar divs com textos e imagens

Tags: html, css, imagem, div

Tenho conhecimento muito básico em html e css, por isso quero a ajuda de vocês para a construção de alguns pontos do layout abaixo usando HTML e CSS.
O **img**  trata de uma imagem de tamanho 100px por 100px.
Observação: O  texto A,B e F tem que ter um espaço entre as imagens e  estar centralizado conforme a imagem abaixo.
O texto C,D e F,  tem que estar embaixo da imagem, porém centralizado conforme é mostrado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conto com a ajuda de vocês !
Obrigada.

No codigo abaixo iniciei a implementação, porém não sei como deixar igual ao demonstrado acima quanto  ao espaço e pular linha para cada imagem dos Texto A    e Texto B.

```
<div id="tudo" >
<div  style=" height:72px;  float:left; background-color:yellow" > 
 <img src="images.png" alt=""   style="width:100px; height:100px;  "/>
       <p style="float:right;  background-color:white"> Ler</p>
  </div>
  <div  style=" height:72px;  float:left; background-color:yellow" > 
 <img src="images.png" alt=""   style="width:100px; height:100px;  "/>
        <p style="float:right;  background-color:white"> Ler</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao sopt. O que você já tentou?

Comment: Entendo, mas seria interessante você tentar, no site, a gente está sempre disposto a ajudar quem precisa, porém pedir coisas prontas é meio que aproveitar da boa vontade de quem quer te ajudar. :/ Comece primeiro clicando nas tags html e css para ver outros conteudos para ter uma noção do que está fazendo, ai quando tiver uma base, edite a pergunta e adicionae-a, assim fica mais facil ajudar :)

Comment: Diego Obrigada,  melhorei a pergunta, realmente já pesquisei na net e etc o que ocorre aqui é q tah faltando pratica

Answer (score 2):

O comando para centralizar verticalmente em [css](/questions/tagged/css) é [line-height](/questions/tagged/line-height).

Dá uma olhada no código abaixo e veja se lhe atende.

```css
.linha {
  display: table;
  margin: 5px;
  }

.img  {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: solid 3px #000;
  float: left;
}

.texto_img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height:100px; 
  float: left;
}  

.celula {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  }

.legenda {
    text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="linha">
  <div class="img">img 01</div>
  <div class="texto_img">Texto A</div>
</div>

<div class="linha">
  <div class="img">Img 02</div>
  <div class="texto_img">Texto B</div>
</div>

<div class="linha">
    <div class="celula">
      <div class="img">Img 03</div>
      <div class="legenda">Texto C</div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="celula">
      <div class="img">Img 04</div>
      <div class="legenda">Texto D</div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="celula">
      <div class="img">Img 05</div>
      <div class="legenda">Texto </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="linha">
  <div class="img">Img 06</div>
  <div class="texto_img">Texto F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eduardo Mendes, Muito Obrigada! Exatamente oque eu precisava ;), Boa Noite.

Comment: Maravilha. Que bom que lhe serviu. Depois marca a resposta como útil para você.